# In Cognito, how can I rollback my old email after the request of changing a new wrong email

Tags: email, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito in my service and I want to enable my service to change email address.
In my frontend, I added code like this.

```js
    const email = 'foo@example.com'; // input
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, { email });
```

I found this `updateUserAttributes` not only send verification email, but also change email address and set `Email verified` false before verification success.

When a user send wrong email address, I think, the user will no longer login, because the user cannot access to verification code and login old email.

Is there functions like rollback old email address in Cognito?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found [the related issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/987)

> I found this updateUserAttributes not only send verification email, but also change email address and set Email verified false before verification success.

Unfortunately, this is Cognito side problem, and now there is no way to solve it fundamentally.

In the issue, [Can-Sahin approach](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/987#issuecomment-508059168) may help you.